# What is "Module" in win32 API function GetModuleFileName or GetModuleHandle?

Tags: c++, api, winapi

In win32 , in some cases we need a Module handle to perform some action.
But I don't know what is a Module exactly.
Help me please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program executes within virtual memory space created by the OS when the program is loading. The program itself and all of the dynamic link libraries loaded in the virtual memory space are called modules. The HMODULE, or HINSTANCE is the address within the virtual memory where the particular module is loaded. You can use GetModuleInstance() or LoadLibrary() API calls to get the handles.

Comment: therefore , in some application we might have more than one module handle , is that true? (for each dll , one module.)

Comment: There will be one module for the executable, and one module for each DLL that is loaded into the process.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. There is nothing preventing you from having more module handles to different modules or even the same module. Usually when you need the handle you should use the handle of your program module. This one is passed in as a parameter in WinMain or DllMain and can be retrieved by `GetModuleHandle(NULL);`

Comment: @SandiHrvić Each module has a unique handle. Two modules have the same handle value if and only if they refer to the same module. In fact the module handle is nothing more than the base address of the module. From which the preceding statement can be inferred.

Comment: David you are right, of course, but I already stated as much in the original answer. In the comment I was trying to say that you can have multiple handles to the same module, without mentioning pointers because that word usually opens another can of worms :)

Comment: And I'm saying that you can't have multiple handles to the same module.

Comment: Sorry, but you're wrong. A handle is nothing more than a void pointer and you can have as many as you want. The fact that they all point to the same address has nothing to do with the number of handles you can have.

Comment: You can have multiple handles (more than one variable holding the handle) but these handles will have the same value. However, this value is an implementation detail and at some point in the future it could change. As stated, currently, the handle is simply the VA of the base of that module. Regarding uniqueness, note that a module handle is valid only within the process the module handle was acquired in.

Comment: Note that `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` never gets module handle of a loaded `DLL` as mentioned here in comments, but of an `EXE` which was used to create a process! to get a module handle of DLL you need to specify name of a DLL into a `GetModuleHandle`